# Azure Function v1 Post Build task failed with Illegal Characters error message

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I created an Azure function v1

Build succeeds

But the post build task that should generate the Azure Function itself fails with the following error

```
2><path>\1.0.38\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(44,6): error : System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
2><path>\1.0.38\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(44,6): error :    à System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
2><path>\1.0.38\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(44,6): error :    à System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
2><path>\1.0.38\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(44,6): error :    à MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.<GenerateFunctions>d__11.MoveNext()
2><path>\1.0.38\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(44,6): error :    à System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
2><path>\1.0.38\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(44,6): error :    à System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
2><path>\1.0.38\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(44,6): error :    à MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryGenerateFunctionJsons()
2><path>\1.0.38\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(44,6): error :    à MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryRun()
2><path>\1.0.38\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(44,6): error : Error generating functions metadata
2><path>\1.0.38\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(44,6): error :
2><path>\1.0.38\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(44,6): error : Metadata generation failed.
```

There is no indication of the path that is evaluated, of course.

I already tried solutions provided in the following articles but it did not help:

- [Illegal character in path when running azure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57297401/illegal-character-in-path-when-running-azure-function)

What can I do more? Is there any way to find a detailed log for this post build task?

Thank you

Comment: Long guess, but in your `Get sources` part you might want to clean all build directories.
To see more detailed output in your build , while queueing set the variable System.Debug with value True

Comment: I already cleaned the solution, deleted bin and obj folder. That didn't help
When you say, set the variable System.Debug with value True, where can I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were talking about a build in azure devops. In this case assuming you have already deleted mentioned directory in your link, other solution would be to update your package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions to a version at least 3.0.11

Comment: Yeah, I know but this is not something I can do. Assemblies I'm using are not compatible with .net core

Comment: In this case please provide more details, how your project is configured and what are deviations from standard function app in .net core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so shame on me. The issue was on the naming of the function. It cannot contains invalid characters for a file  path

[image]